# [DART]: Telling dart generics that an attribute will exist when used

Tags: flutter, dart

Not sure if I'm using generics properly but is there a way I can let `<T>` know that it has (or will have) a certain attribute when it's used? This wouldn't be a problem if it weren't generics but since it's not I keep getting the error `The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'T & Object'.`

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  List<T> items = [];
  
  removeById(int id) {
    items.removeWhere((T element) => element.id! == id);        // Error
  }
}
```

Comment: You can constrain the type of T like this `class Foo<T extends SomeBaseClass>`. See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Comment: @BGPark Thanks for the link! I extended it to one of the base classes which had an id. It works now although I'm slightly (only slightly) feeling a bit uncomfortable having to limit it to the extended class.

Comment: You either can have compile-time checking or runtime type-checking.  If you want duck-typing, then it needs to be done at runtime: `items.removeWhere((element) => (element as dynamic).id == id);`.

Comment: @jamesdlin This is a great idea. Can you post this as a solution so I can mark it? The only minor downside I see is instead of `MyClass item` it's instead `dynamic item`. But it's good nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have either static (compile-time) checks or runtime checks.  For compile-time checks, you would need to parameterize your generic on some base interface.  For example:

```dart
abstract class HasId {
  int get id;
}

class MyClass implements HasId {
  @override
  final int id;

  MyClass(this.id);
}

class Foo<T extends HasId> {
  ...
}
```

If you really want duck-typing, that inherently requires using `dynamic` to disable static type-checking and relying on runtime checks:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  List<T> items = [];
  
  void removeById(int id) {
    items.removeWhere((element) => (element as dynamic).id! == id);
  }
}
```

If there's a possibility that instances of `T` might not have an `id` member, you will need to catch a potential `NoSuchMethodError` yourself.